# JS - function return false

Tags: javascript

I found this code and I'm wondering why is set to return false?

```
    $("#_plan").on('click', function() {
    showChoose();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: It makes sense for a form but not for a button: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569072/jquery-cancel-form-submit-using-return-false

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Returning false from the `click` handler prevents the default action from execution. For example if `#_plan` is a submit button or an anchor returning false will prevent the browser from redirecting away from the current page (which is what happens when you submit a form or click on an anchor).

As an alternative you could use the following:

```
$("#_plan").on('click', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    showChoose();
});
```

This way the browser will remain on the same page and leave time for the `showChoose` function to execute.