# jquery, submit form after google maps geocoding

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have a form which collects a persons address.  When they click submit I want to geocode their address, and use that to fill lat and lng fields.  Here is what I am doing now which is based on the 2nd answer here [submit form does not stop in jquery ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804946/submit-form-does-not-stop-in-jquery-ajax-call)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var geocoder;
        var address;
        $('#theform').submit(function() {
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            address = $('#id_street').val() + " " + $('#id_street2').val() + " " + $('#id_city').val() + ", " + $('#id_state').val() + " " + $('#id_zip').val();
            geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
              if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                $('#id_lat').val(results[0].geometry.location.lat().toFixed(6));
                $('#id_lng').val(results[0].geometry.location.lng().toFixed(6));
                $('#theform').unbind('submit');
                $('#theform').submit();
              } else {
                $('#theform').unbind('submit');
                $('#theform').submit();
              }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

and the form

```
<form method="POST" id="theform" action="">
    <li><label for="id_street">Street</label> <input id="id_street" type="text" name="street" value="3520 Lebon Dr." maxlength="100" /></li>
    <li><label for="id_street2">Street2 (optional)</label> <input id="id_street2" type="text" name="street2" maxlength="100" /></li>
    <li><label for="id_city">City</label> <input id="id_city" type="text" name="city" value="San Diego" maxlength="50" /></li>
    <li><label for="id_state">State</label> <select name="state" id="id_state">
    ...a bunch of state options...
    <li><label for="id_zip">Zip Code</label> <input id="id_zip" type="text" name="zip" value="92122" maxlength="30" /></li>
    <label for="id_lat">Latitude</label><input type="text" name="lat" value="0.000000" id="id_lat" />
    <label for="id_lng">Longitude</label><input type="text" name="lng" value="0.000000" id="id_lng" />
</form>
```

The lat and lng fields get filled fine, but the form does not actually get submitted by $('#theform').submit().  To actually submit the form you have to click submit again.

Any ideas about what I am doing wrong?
And in case anyone asks I do want to submit the form even if geocoding is unsuccessful as in that case I will be using geopy to geocode the address server side.

edit:
Ok so I made a really simple example and can't get submit to work at all:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#subby').click(function() {
        $('#theform').submit();
    });
});

</script>

</head>
<body>
<a href="#" id="subby">Submit</a>
<form id="#theform" action="javascript:alert('success!');">
      <input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I would expect that when clicking the link Submit you would get an alertbox just like when you click the submit button, but this is not the case.  What am I doing wrong with submit?

Comment: Have you run it through a debugger? It could be possible that the first time you run the method the `return false;` is hit, which would stop the submit.

Comment: I put a breakpoint on the return false and $('#theform').unbind('submit'); in the if.  It hit the return false first but then (presumably when the asynch call to google came back) hit the other breakpoint as well after which it should go to $('#theform').submit().  The form was still not submitted though.

Comment: So it did hit a `$('#theform').submit()`? Is there a way you could edit your code so that the `return false` is in an `if` or `else`. Though it goes back to the previous break point I am guessing that hitting that `return false` is confusing the program

Comment: Yeah it did hit $('#theform').submit(), I tried putting a break point there and it would get there.  I'm not sure how I could use a conditional since the call to google is asynchronous. I need it to always be false so it doesn't submit the form before google returns the lat and lng.  I edited my question and added a really simple example of submit that I cannot get to work.  Could you test it out and see if you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is it still not working? If so Ill take a look at it when I get home

Comment: The little example I made still does not work, but I did solve my main problem.  I would still be curious about why the example doesn't work if you have any ideas.

Comment: I think what is wrong with the example is that you never gave it a `method`. When it is submitted the form does not know what to do, so it does nothing

Comment: try adding `method = "post"` and see if that works

Comment: still no dice, I'm not too worried about it though because I have the original problem working.  It may be related to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/645555/should-jquerys-form-submit-not-trigger-onsubmit-within-the-form-tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out.  I accidentally omitted my submit button from the form I posted.  It was named submit.  Apparently that mucks things up for jquery (thanks here: [jQuery doesn't submit a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117755/jquery-doesnt-submit-a-form)).  The simple example I posted still isn't working and I'm not sure why but my actual problem is solved.