# javascript form submiting dosen't work

Tags: javascript, forms, submit, form-submit

i have this code:

```
      <script type="text/javascript" >

          function Run()
         {
             document.forms['SF'].submit();
         }

     </script>


     <form method="post" action="#" name="SF" id="SF">

       <input type="text" id="user" name="user">
       <input type="button" onclick="Run();" value="sd">
       <input hidden type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" >

    </form>
```

that when i click the button it should submit the form but it do nothing..

help please..

Comment: Why you want `JS` to submit when by default `type=submit` always submits and why `action="#"`

Comment: Duplicate of [jQuery doesn't submit a form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117755/jquery-doesnt-submit-a-form) (although, as Mr. Alien says, the real solution here is to use a real submit button and not add JavaScript that provides no benefits at all).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'submit' of object #<HTMLFormElement> is not a function
```

This means that you're trying to access a *property*, this is because your name of the submit button is also `submit`, change its name and it'll work.

You are confusing the form element by overriding the `submit` method with a property name.

#### [Here is a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mza3U/)